# jquery ajax value to php variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hi guys i been fighting with this im trying to pass a jquery value to a php variable

this is my code

```
$('body').on('change','#select_ref',function(){
    var name = $(this).val();
    var dataString = "name=" + name;
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "referencia_select.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // console.debug(data);
            $('#vendedor').val(data.id_vendedor);
            $('#name').val(data.name);
            $('#email').val(data.email);
            $('#compa').val(data.lastname);
            $('#rfc').val(data.rfc);
            $('#phone').val(data.phone);
            $('#fax').val(data.fax);
            $('#address').val(data.address);
            $('#estado').val(data.estado);
            $('#city').val(data.city);
            $('#zipcode').val(data.cp);
            $('#productos').val(data.productos);
        }

    });
});
```

i already try sending it with cookies

```
var productos = data.productos;
document.cookie = "products=" + productos ;
console.log(productos);
```

on my php

try

```
$variable = $_POST['products']; 
$variable = $_COOKIE['products'];
```

and different methods  with not luck any subjection to make this work for my application

im able to chage a input with the data

```
<input type="text" name="productos" id="productos" value="" data-array="12,12,Productos" />
```

but i really need it in a php variable 
thanks a lot

Comment: In your dataString you did not pass a parameter named products that is why you cant get the value. Try to display your posted values like var_dump($_POST) in your php to help you understand what did you pass in your ajax post request.

Answer (score 1):

Send it in the AJAX data.

```
$('body').on('change','#select_ref',function(){
    var name = $(this).val();
    var dataObj = {name: name, products: data.productos};
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "referencia_select.php",
        data: dataObj,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // console.debug(data);
            $('#vendedor').val(data.id_vendedor);
            $('#name').val(data.name);
            $('#email').val(data.email);
            $('#compa').val(data.lastname);
            $('#rfc').val(data.rfc);
            $('#phone').val(data.phone);
            $('#fax').val(data.fax);
            $('#address').val(data.address);
            $('#estado').val(data.estado);
            $('#city').val(data.city);
            $('#zipcode').val(data.cp);
            $('#productos').val(data.productos);
        }

    });
});
```

Then it will be in `$_POST['products']`.